# Extjs Clickable tooltip

Tags: extjs, tooltip, clickable

I have a situation where I roll over a row in a grid, I want to display a menu. I put the menu in a tooltip. But can't click on a menu unless I make the tooltip closable. If I make the tooltip closable, I can't provide the use the autohide functionality and I have to click to close the tooltip. Is there any way to mouseover rows in a grid, show a tooltip that includes clickable items and then have the tooltip goaway when you scroll off of it?

Answer (score 0):

you may need extend your own component from tooltip.

Comment: Maybe this is correct, but it is not of great help.